# Bootstrap 4 navbar's hamburger expands but does not collapse

Tags: html, css, laravel, bootstrap-4

```
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

/* i was trying to put logo in far left, home about in the center and log in to the right. I did that but the hamburger does not work properly in mobile view. It expands but does not collapse*/

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white shadow-sm nav-font">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="/storage/img/msprojectlogo.png" style="width:30%;">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-md-center" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item p-1 pl-4"><a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item p-1 pl-4"><a class="nav-link" href="/about">About</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item p-1 pl-4"><a class="nav-link" href="/services">Services</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item p-1 pl-4"><a class="nav-link" href="/posts">Blog</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item p-1 pl-4">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#') }}</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item p-1 pl-4">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works,

You can add **Bootstrap CSS CDN**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins">
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark shadow-sm nav-font">
      <div class="container">
          <a href="#">
              <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2xkQ.png" style="width:50%;">
          </a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-md-center" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                  <li class="nav-item p-1 pl-4"><a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item p-1 pl-4"><a class="nav-link" href="/about">About</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item p-1 pl-4"><a class="nav-link" href="/services">Services</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item p-1 pl-4"><a class="nav-link" href="/posts">Blog</a></li>
              </ul>
              <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                  <li class="nav-item p-1 pl-4">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#') }}</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item p-1 pl-4">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: It does not work in my pc but I tried doing in online text editor and it worked. https://imgur.com/AvL9dlf This is how it shows on my web browser